# What am I missing to get a global variable to work in a function?

Tags: php, global

I am new to php and unsure why this global call is not working. I am trying to get the URL (Wordpress site) and export the facebook sharing URL to a shortcode.
My current output is simply "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u="

```
$dhURL = urlencode(get_the_permalink());

function facebookshare_function() {
    global $dhURL;
    $FBURL = 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='.$dhURL;
    return $FBURL;
}
add_shortcode('facebookshare', 'facebookshare_function');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your global call is correct.
Why are you using urlencode() on get_the_permalink()?

Simply use `get_the_permalink()` or `esc_url(get_permalink())`

The second one will not encode /

Comment: urlencode was on advice for compatibility. Looks much better without!
So if I've written the global call correctly, any idea why it is not working?

Comment: If you check with a random string as $dhURL, it works fine. So get_the_permalink() is resulting null

Comment: If I use get_the_permalink() inside the function it works properly and returns as intended. I want to have it outside the function (and thus global) though as it will be used in other functions

Comment: Try by adding global $dhURL; also before you declare it. So before get_the_permalink. Child functions variables are strange. Check comments on the page "Variable scope" of the manual

Comment: Do you mean add global $dhURL; before the declaration outside of the function? I have tried that and no success.
It seems as though $dhURL = get_permalink(); does not want to work outside of the function for some reason